# Why does it take time to do nothing?

Tags: javascript

This js code does practically nothing however it takes time to run. Not only that the time varies every time is run.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Measure Time</title></head>
<body>
<script>
var t0 = performance.now();
//Literally Nothing
var t1 = performance.now();
document.write((t1-t0)+" ms");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It gives me 0ms here: https://jsfiddle.net/bt6dejza/ you're adding them together, not finding the difference...

Comment: Changed to t1-t0 and still time varies

Comment: Yeah, well, it's not doing *literally nothing*. Calling `performance.now` is *something*.

Comment: It varies negligibly. Typical output is `0.005000000000009663 ms`. Some runs it outputs `0 ms`.

Comment: Allocating a variable with the `var` keyword is also not "nothing".

Comment: @Asaph Except there is *no* "var allocation" on said line. There is an *assignment* to a local variable, which is .. just an assignment. (Note: it does not matter *where* `var x` appears in a function for it to have the exact same effect.)

Comment: It is doing "literally nothing", which is different than "time has stopped" .. 1) time always passes 2) for some amount of time, and some precision of `now`, there is a difference between values returned

Comment: @user2864740 Looks to me like var t0 and var t1 are being allocated.

Comment: @Asaph "Allocation" is what it may *look* like. That is not what is occurring. The `var` keyword is an *annotation* hidden in a declaration and is *not* tied to any "allocation" (which is not specified unser ECMAScript). Different languages have different rules (JavaScript != Java != C, etc.). There are plenty of SO questions going into the little details.

Comment: @Asaph For example, check out: `x = 2; f = function () { return x = 3; var x; }` - what is the result of `f()`? What is the result of `x` after evaluation of `f()`? Don't fiddle it first ;-) So what *is* occurring? An *assignment* to a local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes time to run because everything in computers takes some sort of time to run.

This could include a browser parsing your script and running it as code (since you're providing it in ASCII). This could include allocating space for variables, or adding a function call onto a call stack.

Performance.now is getting the current time, which requires a system call if I'm not mistaken. That means that the browser has to ask the OS to tell it what the current time is.

The biggest reason why the runtime varies, though, is because of scheduling.

It's possible that the browser won't run those two lines one after the other at the same time. The browser may run one line, take some time off to do something else, then come back and run the second one. It's possible that the browser will try to run both lines one after the other, but the OS will pause execution of whatever code the browser is trying to run in order to let some other program do it's thing.

It may seem like your computer can do a lot of things at the same time, but realistically, each processor core can only run one program at a time. Your computer makes it appear as though many things are happening at once, though, by switching between programs very quickly.

The amount of time each program gets varies based on many factors determined by the person who wrote the OS. Because of this, it's very difficult to predict how long code will take to execute in real time.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks everyone.